# Are these potted mint plants healthy?

Tags: diseases, watering, cuttings, mint

These are some mint plants (Mentha arvensis) that have been grown from grocery store edible mint stems planted in a 60~40 ratio of cocopeat-perlite-compost and garden soil. The new leaves around the meristems seem to be too yellow though. This is planted in a 30 cm diameter rimmed pot. Is this natural or sign of something else? These were planted almost 20~40 days ago or so, and all these leaves are new. Old ones had died and been plucked off. This gets full sun here in Delhi for 6~8 hours. I have been watering it with drinking water since 15 days or so.

Another thing, is it okay to plant newer nursery brought mint plants like this or should I start with smaller pots?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they look okay. Mine looked just like that some months ago. I’m not too familiar with the climate in Delhi, but my experience, my mints didn't like full blown sun in blazing hot days. Also, they get really thirsty in the warmer season.  [image: a year later]